# JPA - How to persist an entity having auto generated id and its associated entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class which uses auto generated id from database (PostgreSQL). It has been persisting fine without requiring me to specify an id to it. e.g.

```
@Entity public class MyEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    // ... other columns
}
```

Now I want to add a List of associated entities owned by this entity class with uni-directional association. e.g.

```
@Entity public class MyEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name="pid")
    private List<SubEntity> subEntities;
    // ... other columns
}

@Entity public class SubEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id private Integer pid;  // refer to id of MyEntity
    @Id private String name;  // pid, name forms a composite key for SubEntity
    // ... other columns
}
```

Then I bumped into an issue that JPA (Hibernate in this case) was generating SQLs like:

```
INSERT INTO MYENTITY (...) VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO SUBENTITY (pid, ...) VALUES (null, ...)
```

It failed when trying to insert a null value to pid as it has not null constraint in the database schema. If I bypass this, Hibernate then generates an update statement to update the null value with the generated id from MyEntity:

```
UPDATE SUBENTITY SET pid = ? WHERE pid = null AND name = ?
```

I get that the auto generated id is not known until after the insert to MyEntity, so it updates afterward. But I wonder if there is a solution so that Hibernate does the insert to MyEntity ONLY first, get the generated id THEN does the inserts to SubEntity with the correct pid and no update afterward?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. Please create an issue in the [Hibernate issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/) with a [test case](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces this issue. Apart from that, I would suggest you try using a sequence generator as that is more scalable anyway.